# Objective-C. How to concatenate two MKPolyline s

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I want to construct a `MKPolyline` from another two. How to do that in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume line1 and line2 have some value. Create a new array with their points and use the [MKPolyline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MKPolyline/polylineWithPoints:count:) constructor to create a new one.

```
//MKPolyline *line1, *line2;
    MKMapPoint mapPoints[line1.pointCount + line2.pointCount];
    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < line1.pointCount + line2.pointCount; i++)
    {
        mapPoints[i] = (i < line1.pointCount) ? line1.points[i] : line2.points[i-line1.pointCount];
    }

    MKPolyline *combinedLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:mapPoints count:line1.pointCount + line2.pointCount];
```